# Tkinter sequential show/hide image not working

Tags: python, image, tkinter

I want to show a basic animation using tkinter: an exclamation mark blinking three times. I created three buttons: one shows the image with the exclamation mark, one hides it, and one shows/hides the image three times. The first two work fine, so the `.pack()` and `.pack_forget()` methods are working on the image, but the last one isn't displayed at all: the button is busy for six seconds (the animation duration) and the tk window is unresponsive (I can't even move the tk window on my screen). There is no error, the `One Blink` text is displayed correctly. Here is the code:

```
import tkinter as tk
import sys
import time

def exclamation_animation(keystroke = ''):
    for i in range(3):
        print('One Blink')
        image_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)     
        time.sleep(1)
        image_label.pack_forget()
        time.sleep(1)

def exclamation_show():
    image_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

def exclamation_hide():
    image_label.pack_forget()

if __name__ == '__main__':

    root = tk.Tk()
    main_frame = tk.Frame(root, height=500, width=500)
    main_frame.pack(side=tk.BOTTOM, fill='both')
    main_frame.pack_propagate(0)

    animation_button = tk.Button(main_frame, command=exclamation_animation, text='Animation')
    show_button = tk.Button(main_frame, command=exclamation_show, text='Show')
    hide_button = tk.Button(main_frame, command=exclamation_hide, text='Hide')

    for button in [animation_button, show_button, hide_button]:
        button.pack(side=tk.LEFT)

    imagefile = "ex.gif"    
    img = tk.PhotoImage(file=imagefile, format = 'gif')
    image_label = tk.Canvas(main_frame, width=120, height=500)  
    image_label.create_image(img.width()//2, img.height()//2, image=img)

    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the **main_frame.update()** after image_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT) and image_label.pack_forget() in the animation function.

```
def exclamation_animation(keystroke = ''):
for i in range(3):
    print('One Blink')
    image_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)   
    main_frame.update()  
    time.sleep(1)
    image_label.pack_forget()
    main_frame.update()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

`time.sleep` blocks the main thread of tkinter. You can use `root.after` instead to trigger a callback every 1 second:

```
def exclamation_animation(keystroke = '',interval=[0]):
    print('One Blink')
    image_label.pack(side=tk.LEFT)
    image_label.pack_forget()
    interval[0]+=1
    if interval[0]<3:
        root.after(1000, exclamation_animation)
    else:
        interval[0] = 0
```